# Visual C++ GUI explanation needed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, user-interface

I am new to c++ GUI and would like to know more

```
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Goodbye, cruel world!", "Note", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Would someone be kind enough to explain what `HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,PSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow`do?

Comment: Its the well documented GUI entry-point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can't i just write MessageBox(NULL, "Goodbye, cruel world!", "Note", MB_OK); like in C#

Comment: Do you mean without a WinMain()? would it work in C# without a Main() ?

Comment: i meant like  public static void Main()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Hello, World!");.can't it be like that

Comment: No, it can't be like that. C++ is a different programming language than C#. The fact that the entry point looks different is an obvious consequence of that difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find information here:
[theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial - Getting Started](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html)